# Is smoothness of $X\to Y$ for noetherian $X$ a local property on $X$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $X$ be a noetherian scheme. If $X$ is regular, then the scheme $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_{X,x})$ is regular for all points $x\in X$. I wonder if something analog is true for smoothness of a morphism. More precisely, let $f\colon X\to Y$ be a smooth morphism and $x\in X$ a point with canonical morphism $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_{X,x})\to X$. Is the composite morphism $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_{X,x})\to X\to Y$ necessarily smooth?

Answer (score 0):

A smooth morphism is demanded to be locally finitely presented, so even the map $Spec \mathcal{O}_{X,x} \rightarrow X$ need not be smooth.